# RestSharp AddFile using key and image in C#

Tags: c#, post, postman, restsharp

I´m trying to consume a Rest service that receives an image with a key. I am using RestSharp v.106.10.1 in Visual Studio 2017. I have the following code, which when executing returns a message with the server response that says the package has arrived without the image. Can you help me on what am I doing wrong?.

This is my code

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3030/api/upload-image");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddFile("images", "/C:/Users/Desktop/AppTestWM/ServidorFTP/450_1000.jpg");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The way to send from postman is this. the header contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  and the body in form-data added a key “image” and the image file.

This is header format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EivDN.png)

This is body format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/curgj.png)

MORE IINFORMATION

This is postman console good answer

POST http://localhost:3000/imagenSoliTag/upload-image

• ▶Network

▶Request Headers

User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1

Accept: /

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 44761995-f969-417d-9216-c98d2ee38b35

Host: localhost:3000

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------- -505415277809498326289672

Content-Length: 20233

• ▶Request Body

▶image: {…}

_events: {}

_eventsCount: 3

▶_readableState: {…}

autoClose: true

bytesRead: 20022

closed: true

domain: null

fd: null

flags: "r"

mode: 438

path: "C:\Users\Desktop\AppTestWM\ServidorFTP\450_1000.jpg"

readable: false

▶Response Headers

X-Powered-By: Express

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 71

ETag: W/"47-DTIxeI6y0HsQCMVrZcYol72rDDs"

Date: Sun, 19 Apr 2020 23:42:08 GMT

Connection: keep-alive

• ▶Response Body

response: "¡Imagen guardada con éxito!"

imagePath: "450_1000.jpg"

This is postman console bad answer when make a query without image

POST http://localhost:3000/imagenSoliTag/upload-image

• ▶Network

▶Request Headers

User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1

Accept: /

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 9903417e-e3f0-467e-a185-046a1043ba45

Host: localhost:3000

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

• Request Body

▶Response Headers

X-Powered-By: Express

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 50

ETag: W/"32-Z/sIWz99etyVziu3PXRpXUZOG6c"

Date: Sun, 19 Apr 2020 23:44:07 GMT

Connection: keep-alive

• ▶Response Body

statusCode: 400

message: "¡Elija una imagen!"

This is Visual studio debug in Request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHEv3.png)

and in Response debug is this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZsD3.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question.

See the Content-Type sent by postman:

[image]

And this is the request you are posting with RestSharp (gathered using [Fiddler 4](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler))

```
POST /api/upload-image HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/106.0.0.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299
Host: oguzozgul.com.tr
Content-Length: 19006
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

It is actually trying to send the form using boundaries, but you are forcing it to send the Content-Type header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Set the header Content-Type as multipart/form-data, or (works with the latest version), let RestSharp set the Content-Type automatically by not forcing it to use a specific (and incorrect) one: (The statement setting the Content-Type header is removed:)

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3030/api/upload-image");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddFile("images", "/C:/Users/Desktop/AppTestWM/ServidorFTP/450_1000.jpg");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. any other idea? please!!

Comment: The please provide the full response message, or debyg information, whatever information you have

Comment: It posts the Content-Type as null. What version of restsharp are you using? The final NuGet version puts the correct content-type header, but your is sending null and that is the error.

Comment: I edited my answer to set the Content-Type header manually. Try this, and if it does not work, Please upgrade to the latest version of RestSharp.